# Print string in a form of Unicode codes

Tags: python, string, unicode

How can I print a string as a sequence of unicode codes in Python?

Input: `"если"` (in Russian).

Output: `"\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
>>> s = u'если'
>>> print repr(s)
u'\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438'
```

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
txt = u"если"
print repr(txt)
```

Output:

```
u'\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = u"\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438"
print "".join("\u{0:04x}".format(ord(c)) for c in a)
```

Comment: Sure, but it gives unicode also for ascii-characters, which may be desireable. But you should have had a ''.join() around that list comprehension. ;)

Comment: @Lennart: Yes, thanks for that. Extracting the string from the return value of repr is a bit tedious (and is gonna change in Python 3, because the u prefix is gone).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a specific encoding, you can use :

```
txt = u'если'
print txt.encode('utf8')
print txt.encode('utf16')
```